# How to list readline variables with their current value

Tags: bash, command-line, autocomplete, readline

I'd like to be able to see if, for example, `show-all-if-unmodified` is enabled in the current session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [`bind -V`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins):

```bsh
$ bind -V | grep show-all-if-unmodified
show-all-if-unmodified is set to `off'
```

As far as I can see, no variable name includes the whole name of a different variable (e.g. there is no `show-all` variable that will also match `show-all-if-unmodified` when used as a non-anchored pattern), nor any special character in the context of regular expressions. Hence it should be safe to define `bind -V | grep` as a shell alias or function.